# How to add methods to DataGridView class

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, extension-methods

my question is simple. How do i add methods to the standard DataGridView control of VB.NET

I want to add some methods of my own to the class, but i tried inheritance and i get errors. What are the techniques out there to extend native classes in vb net

Comment: Inheritance didn't work for me... Thoug extension methods did..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx).